# Talend Open Studio (TOS): Qlik removed the Talend Community. Any backup available?

Tags: talend

Recently Qlik announced to remove any support of Talend Open Studio, but it was stated, that current installations will remain working.

- The Talend Community is already gone.
- Google searches are still hitting articles, but links are broken and not forwarded.

E.g. the search: "talend 8 not saving perspective" leads to this link
https://community.talend.com/s/question/0D53p00007vCrpJCAS/resolved-tos-cant-keep-customised-perspectives?language=en_US
Which contained the information I'm looking for, but it shows only a text like
"Looking for Qlik Talend Support? Click here to log into our Support Portal. Looking for articles and discussions? We've moved to the Qlik Community!"

Is there any way to get to the historic data of the Talend Community?
I have tried already:

- https://web.archive.org/
- archive.today

So far without success. Ideally I would like to get a way to search and access the old information permanently. Either with the help of a service such as web.archive.org or by creating an offline version locally.

Since the original content is removed by Qlik already, I'm looking for other Talend users who might have been able to circumvent this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The Talend Community is not gone, but merged into the Qlik Community.

It's true, that links are not forwarded, but you can copy the topic title (in your case "[resolved] TOS can't keep customised perspectives" and [search for it in the Qlik Community](https://community.qlik.com/t5/Search-the-Community/bd-p/qlikSearchUnify?searchString=%5Bresolved%5D%20TOS%20can%27t%20keep%20customised%20perspectives&activeType=all&from=0&sortby=_score&orderBy=desc&pageNo=1&aggregations=%5B%5D&uid=cb43fd48-5178-11eb-8a9b-0242ac120002&resultsPerPage=10&exactPhrase=&withOneOrMore=&withoutTheWords=&pageSize=10&language=en&state=5&suCaseCreate=false) (https://community.qlik.com/).