# Talend Open Studio (TOS) / eclipse IDE: Perspectives not saved / Can't keep customised perspectives

Tags: eclipse, talend

I'm using Talend Open Studio and there is an issue in version 8.0.1. Any changes on existing Perspectives as well as newly created Perspectives are not stored persistently. The customizations get lost every time when I close and re-open TOS.

- In version 7.3.1 this works perfectly fine
- it is broken in Version 8.0.1
- I suspect this might be an eclipse issue or a eclipse misconfiguration in Talend 8
- Since TOS is a complex customization/extension based on eclipse, I have no idea what might interfere with the perspective save/load, which is standard feature of eclipse.org

Has anyone an idea on how to convince TOS 8.0.1 to keep changes and new custom perspectives?

What have I tried so far?

- I found that perspectives are stored in the workspace at this place: `WORKSPACE_ROOT\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench\workbench.xmi`
- I can see that on close of eclipse/TOS, this file will update
- I can find my perspective in the file after eclipse/TOS is closed in the contend of workbench.xmi
- Now when I start eclipse/TOS again, I can see that workbench.xmi is DELETED. This happen on each start, somehow automatically. Then when I make any change to a perspective, it will get recreated with default settings.
- Now when I remove the filesystem modify/delete persmission, eclipse will start with an exception, but anyway continue to start and my perspective is present. This is a workaround.
- But how to find out, what is deleting the workbench.xmi? I dont want to fiddle around with the permissions for each change.

eclipse releases (maybe unclear version numbers)

- Talend 7.3.1 is based on eclipse 2.2.400 (from 2018)
  [image]
- Talend 8.0.1 is based on eclipse 2.3.600 (from 2021)
  [image]

This issue was addressed and resolved already in the former Talend Community and available at this URL: https://community.talend.com/s/question/0D53p00007vCrpJCAS/resolved-tos-cant-keep-customised-perspectives?language=en_US

As an unfortunate, Qlik has already removed this link with their effort to discontinue TOS. I'm asking about a general solution for any Community Article here: [Talend Open Studio (TOS): Qlik removed the Talend Community. Any backup available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77898346/talend-open-studio-tos-qlik-removed-the-talend-community-any-backup-availabl)

This question is specifically for this issue with the perspectives getting lost.

Comment: There are no such Eclipse releases as 2.2.400 or 2.3.600

Comment: @greg-449 you are probably right. How can I find out the Eclipse release version?

Comment: @greg-449 I've added screenshots

Comment: @greg-449 I can see, that Talend is deleting workbench.xmi on each start. See my update of the question above. This is the reason for the issue (loss of customization). I need to find out which configuration of Talend is deleting workbench.xmi over and over again (on eclipse-startup), and I need to stop it form doing so

Comment: Look in the eclipse.ini (or whatever Talend calls it) for something like `-clearPersistedState`. The "Eclipse RCP" feature matches the Eclipse release - so 4.10 and 4.20, both old.

Comment: @greg-449 there is only TOS_DI-win-x86_64.ini containing

-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx1536m
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m
--add-opens
java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens
java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM

in which folder eclipse.ini should be located? I found TOS_DI-win-x86_64.ini right beside the executable called TOS_DI-win-x86_64.exe in the eclispe/TOS installation root folder. Am I looking in the wrong .ini file?

Comment: I think this might also happen if eclipse is run with -clean option.

Comment: Does this help? I think it might a clone of the broken link you posted: https://community.qlik.com/t5/Installing-and-Upgrading/resolved-TOS-can-t-keep-customised-perspectives/td-p/2393906

Comment: The ini file always has the same name as the executable and is in the same folder so that seems to be correct file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://community.qlik.com/t5/Installing-and-Upgrading/resolved-TOS-can-t-keep-customised-perspectives/td-p/2393906 , which I think might be a copy of the post you were looking for:

> I think that problem come with the "non configuration" of some
> informations on the connection to workspace part.
>
> Then, try this ==>
>
> 1. create a new folder for your workspace
> 2. open TOS DI studio
> 3. click on button "Manage Connections"
> 4. fill in field "Name" with a value other than the default value (default = "Local") * optional
> 5. do the same with field "Description" (default = "Default connection") * optional
> 6. fill in field "User E-mail" with other value than default too (default = "user@talend.com") * REQUIRED !
> 7. continue with opening procedure
> 8. customize your IDE and save (or not) perspective
> 9. close IDE
> 10. re-open IDE, custom perspective is kept (normally, lol)
> 11. if it work, import your previous projects from your previous workspace
>
> Some remarks :
>
> 1. Before doing that, install required third-parties packages
> 2. It's absolutely required to create a new fresh wrokspace, old ones can't work !!
> 3. The only real constraint is the user mail, it's not necessary that it exist in real but it MUST be change !!